# Using SUM() with a window function however getting an error saying a GROUP BY clause is needed for others columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in which I need to perform sums on various ranges. In my understanding, the usage of a window function after an aggregate function allows me to perform 
the aggregation on this window function, and with that I no longer need to have a GROUP BY clause for every column of my request. However when I try to execute the following scenario :

```
DECLARE @TypeAgg nvarchar(100)

SELECT 
c.MyCode AS Code,
...
-- Lots of other scalar column without aggregate function go here
(SUM (
        SELECT PriceTypeA + PriceTypeB + PriceTypeC FROM Orders
        WHERE PriceCode = c.MyCode 
) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE @TypeAgg WHEN N'Daily' THEN OrderDate WHEN N'Monthly' THEN MONTH(OrderDate)) AS PriceForFood
--Others similar sums go here
FROM CodesTable as c
-- Lots of joins go here
GROUP BY CASE @TypeAgg WHEN N'Daily' THEN c.OrderDate WHEN N'Monthly' THEN MONTH(c.OrderDate)
```

I still get the error:

> column 'c.MyCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why is that and how can I fix that ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: No the questions are different, here I am using a window function I shouldn't run into that issue

Comment: Add your full query.

Comment: The error message is both precise and accurate.

Comment: Thanks you all for your replies. There is perhaps something that I don't understand because I persist : for me, my question is different.
I'm in the situation of this example in msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx (see example B).
As you can see, there are not using GROUP BY clauses on non aggregated columns since there are using the OVER CLAUSE.
You are pointing me to a question where the author is not using the OVER clause, thus our situations are different because with the OVER clause i shoudn't run into this issue. This is what my question is about, why is that.

Comment: The `SUM()` is the issue. try changing to `SUM(SELECT PriceTypeA + PriceTypeB + PriceTypeC FROM Orders) OVER (...)`

Comment: @ypercube Thank you, actually I already have that, I made a mistake when typing my question. I've just updated it, really sorry

Comment: Then it's the `GROUP BY CASE ...` that forbids, the use of `c.MyCode` in the `SELECT` list. What if you remove that `GROUP BY` completely?

Comment: It fixes everything... you got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: So my actual problem is that I GROUP BY only one column, and a lot of SO questions deal with that. I didn't realize that, I was looking at the wrong part. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of "scalar column without aggregate function", along with a bunch of aggregate functions. Those "scalar column without aggregate function" need to be in the GROUP BY clause.

You're not doing what your example is doing. They're using `sum() over`, which is a window function. You're using `sum(select... over(...)...)`, which is an aggregate function applied to the result of a window function. Two utterly different things.

---

If you're going to use a GROUP BY clause, every column in the SELECT column-list that's not an argument to an aggregate function must appear in the GROUP BY clause.

You're using a GROUP BY clause in the outermost SELECT statement. So every "scalar column without aggregate function" in the SELECT column-list must also appear in the GROUP BY clause. (There is an exception to this, but it's not supported by SQL Server AFAIK.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I didn't understand : the difference between sum() over and sum( select over()).

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when typing my question, i've just seen that actually I already have a sum() over. I'll update the question with the fix